# Issues with splitting txt file (1 billion rows) into chunks (1.5 mil rows each), unable to figure how to write the remaining rows to last file

Tags: python, java, string, chunks, txt

I'm learning how to operate with files and decided to go big. Generated 30 GB file of random text using small dictionary, file consists of 1 billion rows, every row is 2 strings delimited by space.

My specs: `Ryzen 3600, 16gb 3200 RAM, 512 GB ssd`

Text sample:

```
orthodox_jungle sharp_opera
vertical_referee close_steward
express_wheel intermediate_building
painful_damage similar_fly
violent_justification colourful_opposition
```

So far I was able to chunk the main txt file into many temporary files, that later will be sorted and merged into one whole file again (removing duplicates).

### **Main Problem**

I'm stuck with `while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)` condition. Because the file is being split STRICTLY after counter goes to 1.5 millions (or any other split range, 1 million or 100k), the remaining text is not processed and saved. Also creating new `List` within `while` local scope doesnt let me to save that list to file once the loop is over.

**Method that does the chunking**

```
    public void readFromFileTest(String filePath) throws IOException {

        long start = System.nanoTime();

        String path = "/home/developer/Downloads/tmpfiles/temporaryToSort%d.txt";

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        String line;
        List<String> listToSort = new ArrayList<>();

        int currentLineCounter = 0;
        int temporaryFileCounter = 0;

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (currentLineCounter == 1500000) {

                String tmpFileLocation = String.format(path, temporaryFileCounter);

                sortAndSaveListToFile(tmpFileLocation, listToSort);

                currentLineCounter = 0;
                temporaryFileCounter++;

                listToSort = new ArrayList<>();
            }

            String[] arrayOfWords = line.split(" ");

            for (String word : arrayOfWords) {
                listToSort.add(word + "\n ");
            }
            // \n is needed, because otherwise my temporary textfile would be considered
            //as one single big String of 50 mb size

            //hence i cant use listToSort.addAll(Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")));

            //listToSort.addAll(Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")));
            currentLineCounter++;
        }

        long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.printf("Took %.3f second to read, sort and write to a file%n", time / 1e9);
    }
```

**Proof that the last piece of text is not processed**

Reading last rows from main and last saved temporary file I get different text samples:

```
public List<String> getLastLinesFromFile(int numLastLineToRead) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File f = new File("/home/developer/Downloads/verylargefile/verylargefile.txt");
//        File f = new File("/home/developer/Downloads/tmpfiles/temporaryToSort665.txt");

        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        try (ReversedLinesFileReader reader = new ReversedLinesFileReader(f, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null && result.size() < numLastLineToRead) {
                result.add(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;

    }
```

returns last rows for main file and tmp respectfully:

```
optimistic_direction senior_ghost
exact_admiration influential_cereal
useful_rice charismatic_syndrome
```

and

```
 main_sweater
 general_review
 current_passion
 afraid_lemon
 stunning_garbage
 presidential_dialect
 low_cathedral
 full_accountant
 crude_survivor
```

### Possible workaround

Simply calculate the number of lines in that file, then replace `while` condition with simple for loop and saving everything when `i = lineCount`. But it takes 85 seconds to count all lines on my machine and it stinks.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.input.ReversedLinesFileReader;

        long lineCount;

        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Path.of(filePath), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
            lineCount = stream.count();
        }

        System.out.println(lineCount);
```

Initial plan was to use RandomAccessFile and read it into byte[] array, allocating 128 MB of memory for that array, and then just saving the remaining of array to last file, but it was too much of a hassle reinventing bufferReaders `readLine()` and file pointer repositioning&seeking to newline byte, then saving chopped string piece to new bytearray.

Any other examples how to effectifely chunk big text files would be appreciated, I know my implementation is hot garbage.

Send help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO all you need is (after the `while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) { /*...*/ }` block

```
if (!listToSort.isEmpty()) {
    String tmpFileLocation = String.format(path, temporaryFileCounter);
    sortAndSaveListToFile(tmpFileLocation, listToSort);
}
```

or if you are using a Java version before Java 11:

```
if (listToSort.size() > 0) {
    String tmpFileLocation = String.format(path, temporaryFileCounter);
    sortAndSaveListToFile(tmpFileLocation, listToSort);
}
```

Comment: So, extra checking ```if (!listToSort.isEmpty())``` 1 billion - 1 times just for that end condition? I guess this will work, we are writing in Java after all.                                    
             EDIT: i missed the "after while" block list sort check. But that wouldnt be possible? I'm moving Lists reference ```listToSort = new ArrayList<>();``` to new list and old list should be killed by GC because it has no references anymore?

Comment: EDIT2: just checked, man, it works, my understanding of scopes was so wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @Baffled_Development the `listToSort` is declared before the while loop, so it is still in scope after the while loop (and it contains an `ArrayList` instance created the last time that `if (currentLineCounter == 1500000)` was true). This last `listToSort` will go out of scope when the method ends and will then be garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend taking a look at split from AT&T's Unix.
A simple solution is to change your while to an inverted until (until the readline returns null) and add an OR'ed condition to the write block ( or not line )